# How to check if a number in a list range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a float number x and a list range list_ = [[a, b], [c,d], [e,f]]

How can check if the number x is in the list. It means the function will return True in case of

```
a<=x <=b
or 
c<=x <=d
or 
e<=x <=f
```

Otherwise, the function will return False. Could you help me to write a Python code for the function

```
function (x, list_)--> True/False
```

Comment: You might find [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic solution would be this:

```
def f(x: int, ls: List[Tuple[float, float]]) -> bool: 
   return any(a <= x <=b for (a, b) in ls)
```

Take specific note of the following:

- Naming a function `function` is a super poor idea.
- It is abnormal and therefore a poor idea to name a variable `list_` just to avoid overriding a keyword.
- Using the form `any` ensures that you quickly quit when you find a valid solution.
- You can quickly destructure your tuple (or list, if you happen to pass a list) using the `for (a, b) in ls` clause.
- This solution is as quick as if you use a for clause, but all of that is premature optimization anyway.
- Using an explicit destructing ensures you have two and only two elements for your sublist.

It was requested that I check certain inputs:

```
>>> f(10.1, [[8.1, 12.1], [110, 120]])
True
```

Seems to work!

If you're running into `NameError`, the issue is simply one of the importation of types. You can either define `f` like so:

```
def f(x, ls):
    ... // As you would otherwise
```

Or import the required types to make the type-hinting work properly:

```
from typing import List, Tuple
def f(x: int, ls: List[Tuple[float, float]]) -> bool: 
    ... // As you would otherwise
```

This has little to do with the original question or solution - it's just standard for type hinting in python.

Comment: Please check with the input
 x= 10.1 and list_=[[8.1, 12.1], [110, 120]]

Comment: Done. Not sure what the concern is here...?

Comment: I got the error `NameError: name 'List' is not defined`

Comment: @MoonLee Updated the answer. it's not an issue with the solution - you're just not importing the types. Usually when you see a `NameError` that is the issue. I do recommend understanding and using the typing and typehint system - it will make code a /lot/ clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Clean solution:

```
def function(x, list_):
    return any([l[0] < x < l[1] for l in list_])
```

Optimized solution:

```
def function(x, list_):
    for l in list_:
        if l[0] < x < l[1]:
           return True
    return False
```

Comment: I think of wants `<=` ;)

Comment: If in your clean solution you remove square brackets, you will get even more optimized solution than your optimized solution.

Comment: Please check the solution. and give some example. I used it but it return False. x= 10.1 and list_=[[8.1, 12.1], [110, 120]]

Comment: While this solution is not idiomatic python, it /does/ work. It properly returns true for your given input.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(x,list__):
    for [a,b] in list_data:
        if a<=x<=b:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the list and find whether it's in range or not.

I'm generating the variable and the list randomly and calling a function that iterates and checks whether the variable lies within the range of any of the members of the list.

```
import numpy as np

def find_if_in_range(list_, var) -> bool:
    for i in list_:
        if i[0] <= var <= i[-1]:
            return True
    return False

var = np.random.randint(10)
list_ = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,2), dtype=np.uint8)
print(f"var: {var}")
print(f"list: {list_}")
res = find_if_in_range(list_, var)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
var: 0
list: [[0 6]
 [2 7]
 [7 9]]
True
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: In what world do you need numpy for this? Or a random number? This is very much overkill and unneeded.

Comment: Simply for explanatory purposes. If you dislike the answer, you can downvote and leave. Not a problem :)

Comment: You can't explain things cleanly if you include a lot of unnecessary junk. Numpy isn't needed for this - you can just use the standard library random generator if you want to 'prove' what is going on. Instead you require the dl and importation of an entire additional library.